# Cannot retrieve View in onResume() method inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have a method in my fragment that I would like to call from `onResume()`. Unfortunately, my method requires that I pass it a View, which is defined in `onCreateView()`:

**onResume():**

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        retrieveData(0, false, rootView);
    }
```

**onCreateView():**

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Set view
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
    ...
    }
```

Is there a way to call my retrieveData method as is in `onResume()`, or should I just create a new method without the rootView parameter (not ideal)?

Can't move it to global scope because the inflater method parameter is part of the fragment interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only get the view from your fragment, not your activity. To do this, in your fragment **onCreateView**

save the root view as an Instance Variable like

```
private View root;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details_buddy, container, false);
... }
```

And call it in your **onResume**

Edit : to get data from Activity, pass it in a *Bundle*. [Doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver)